# Game Maker networking, sending too much data

Tags: networking, game-maker

I am working on a game with Game Maker and am having a little trouble with networking :(  My server is coded in python with the help of Twisted Framework.

Anywho, as an example, when I click a button in my Game Maker game to send my login information to the server, it appears to send it numerous times with a single click of the mouse, which isn't right.  Here is my send script code...

```
var t_buffer = buffer_create(256, buffer_grow, 1)
buffer_seek( t_buffer, buffer_seek_start, 0)
buffer_write( t_buffer , buffer_string, chr(argument0) + string(argument1) )
network_send_packet(obj_Server.client, t_buffer, buffer_tell(t_buffer))
buffer_delete(t_buffer)
```

My server side, for now, I just print out what data was sent, and it prints five lines of the same thing.  Here is my python code...

```
# Sends received data to the protocol handler
def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.protocolHandler(data)

# Parses data sent from the client
def protocolHandler(self, data):
    # Split our data
    #values = data.split("\x01")
    #eventTokens = values.pop(0)
    #eventToken1, eventToken2 = eventTokens
    print "Data Received:: " + str(data) + ": First Character: " + data[0]
```

For explanation sake, the tokens just help me identify what i need to do in game, for example, if I receive \x01\x03 I know it's a login packet, and there should be login data attached.  If I get \x02\x03 I know it's something else like my clients player has died.

How should I be handling the sending of data so that it isn't sending numerous packets?

Comment: Maybe it's using UDP, an unreliable protocol, and it sends everything five times to try to make sure it gets there.

Answer (score 0):

GM shouldn't be sending the data multiple times. Use `show_message( "data sent" );` in your code to see how many times it is actually being executed.

If it's executing multiple times, then you need to look at exactly how you're calling that code.

If it's only executing once, then there must be something up with how you're handling it server side, but I'm not familiar with the Twisted Framework.